# Subscribers added by Youtube API diappearing

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using Youtube Data API V3 to subscribe users to a channel. The subscription process basically tells the users that they will subscribe to certain channels by clicking a button. They can walk away from it if they don't want to subscribe. Once they click the button, they will go through Youtube's authorization process and finish the subscriptions. So there's no cheating or whatever. What I find is that on certain days, there might be over one thousand people that subscribe. Before I'd like to celebrate, all the subscribers on that day are gone. But if the subscription acitivities are not that active, say only dozens of people subscribe, nothing would happen. So I wonder if there's any "soft limit" on the number of subscribers within a period of time for API subscription. Google never mentions such limit but I've encountered this problem several times.

Comment: I think you should ask google about that because it has nothing to do about programming (like problems with the api itself for example).

Comment: You mean like if Google consider the "thousand people that subscribe" like fake, so he removes the subscription ?

Comment: @martialdidit: Google might think it's botting. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @matan7890: Just want to see if other programmers run into the same issue and what can possibly cause this issue from technical perspective. Has already asked the question on Google's product forum but they never answer API related questions.